# python error while ipsec verify under archlinux

Tags: linux, python-3.x, archlinux, ipsec

I've been trying to setup a l2tp vpn connection for my computer, and while following the guide, I felt on a python error on line 84
link to the [Openswan L2TP/IPsec VPN client setup](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Openswan_L2TP/IPsec_VPN_client_setup) guide.

```bash
ipsec verify
```

```
  File "/usr/local/libexec/ipsec/verify", line 84
    print "\t[%s%s%s]"%(FAIL,rtext,ENDC)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[OpenSwan](https://www.openswan.org/) service is up and running, and I've checked in `/etc/ipsec.conf` and `/etc/ipsec.d/` to check if there was anything wrong and it does not look like it,
does anyone have an idea of what I could use for a work around

If you need command output just ask!
Thanks for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error indicates that **you are executing a `python2` script with `python3`**.

```
# python3
print('hi')
# python2
print 'hi'
```

Based on the [xelerance/Openswan's `ipsec/verify` source](https://github.com/xelerance/Openswan/blob/ed1a93c029457fa083b68087c1f591f3495887c3/programs/verify/verify.in#L93), the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (first line of the script) indicates it will be using `/usr/bin/python` which in your case, on ArchLinux, is python3 ;)

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
```

As described in the [archlinux python wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/python#Python_2) you may replace `python` with `python2` directly on the file and it should start running again.

You could probably do a pull request directly on the project to ask for `python3` support or at least using an `env` shebang like the following:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

You can also manually change the file on your system with a python2 shebang

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

As long as you have python2 installed on your system ;)